# Refresh/Update a DIV via basic JavaScript not jQuery or AJAX

Tags: javascript

First things first, I **DO NOT** want my code to be in **jQuery OR AJAX**! I'd like it to be in pure JavaScript. I know jQuery and AJAX are way faster and better as OOP goes, but I only know a little bit of JavaScript and want to learn how to do the following in basic JavaScript before I go on to higher versions like AJAX and jQuery.

So anyone who can make this work for me thanks :)

---

All I want to have done is instead of refreshing the entire page/window, I'd like to have only the **DIV** with an id of **#tips** to be refreshed/updated with content from an external ("tips.txt") file. I'm trying to learn how to do this in basic JS instead of the more up-to-date methods so I can learn from the bottom and work my way up.

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: `basic JS instead of the more up-to-date methods.` Why? Also, you need to give more detail on your scenario. Update how? and from where?

Comment: update with what(data from the server, user input, etc..)? also, ajax is not a js library, it's actually plain javascript. so if you're trying to update your div with data from the server then you'll have to use ajax. jquery on the other hand IS a js library and presents ajax to you in a different way.

Comment: @Matt: Just update the div with the contents from a tips.txt document stored on the root directory. I'd just like the div to update every 5 seconds so when new tips are added they will be displayed.

Comment: @user2043512 then to open the txt file you'll have to use PHP (html5 will have a way to do this but it's still in the works) and have js call that php file using ajax along with `setTimeout` (so it can be called every 5sec). I think you should learn more about ajax first especially the part about "asynchronous".

Answer (score 0):

AJAX can be pure JavaScript. This has nothing to do with jQuery. With jQuery it's just easier to make a request, because it's a JavaScript framework.
http://www.seifi.org/javascript/simple-ajax-request-response-javascript.html